# astropy.io fits efficient element access of a large table

Tags: python, arrays, fits, astropy

I am trying to extract data from a binary table in a FITS file using Python and astropy.io. The table contains an events array with over 2 million events. What I want to do is store the TIME values of certain events in an array, so I can then do analysis on that array. The problem I have is that, whereas in fortran (using FITSIO) the same operation takes maybe a couple of seconds on a much slower processor, the exact same operation in Python using astropy.io is taking several minutes. I would like to know where exactly the bottleneck is, and if there is a more efficient way to access the individual elements in order to determine whether or not to store each time value in the new array. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from astropy.io import fits

minenergy=0.3
maxenergy=0.4
xcen=20000
ycen=20000
radius=50

datafile=fits.open('datafile.fits')
events=datafile['EVENTS'].data


datafile.close()

times=[]

for i in range(len(events)):
    energy=events['PI'][i]
    if energy<maxenergy*1000:
        if energy>minenergy*1000:
            x=events['X'][i]
            y=events['Y'][i]
            radius2=(x-xcen)*(x-xcen)+(y-ycen)*(y-ycen)
            if radius2<=radius*radius:
                times.append(events['TIME'][i])

print times
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am an ok programmer in other languages, but I have not really had to worry about efficiency in Python before. The reason I have chosen to do this in Python now is that I was using fortran with both FITSIO and PGPLOT, as well as some routines from Numerical Recipes, but the newish fortran compiler I have on this machine cannot be persuaded to produce a properly working program (there are some issues of 32- vs. 64-bit, etc.). Python seems to have all the functionality I need (FITS I/O, plotting, etc), but if it takes forever to access the individual elements in a list, I will have to find another solution.

Thanks very much.

Comment: The reason this is slow is that for ever row in your table, you're extracting a column from the table (`events['PI']`) which returns a new `ndarray` object representing that column sliced out of the full table--a very slow operation.  Same with 'X', 'Y', and 'TIME'.  And then you're indexing it with a Python integer, it that has to go into the array, seek to that index, and copy the numeric value out and convert it to a Python `float` object.  Also, if you're using Python 2, the `range()` function is creating a list of 2 million Python `int`s.

Comment: In Python for Data Analysis chapter 12, Wes McKinney suggests making sure arrays are memory contiguous with respect to Fortran or C ordering for best performance for operations over columns or rows respectively.  By default numpy arrays are row contiguous, but some operations such as transpose can change that. This can be checked with the flags property of ndarray. If an array is not in the best memory order it can be changed with copy as in arr.copy('C').flags  to change arr to C (row) memory order or arr.copy('F').flags to change it to F (column) order.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do this using numpy vector operations.  Without special tools like numba, doing large loops like you've done will always be slow in Python because it is an interpreted language.  Your program should look more like:

```
energy = events['PI'] / 1000.
e_ok = (energy > min_energy) & (energy < max_energy)
rad2 = (events['X'][e_ok] - xcen)**2 + (events['Y'][e_ok] - ycen)**2
r_ok = rad2 < radius**2
times = events['TIMES'][e_ok][r_ok]
```

This should have performance comparable to Fortran.  You can also filter the entire event table, for instance:

```
events_filt = events[e_ok][r_ok]
times = events_filt['TIMES']
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This makes it run in less than a second. Could you please explain what it is doing with the new code and how it is different from what it was doing before?

Comment: As nice as Python is as a language, it was never designed for writing efficient numerical code.  It was designed as a toy language in a computer science department to try out some language design ideas, but sort of took off for there.  That's why we have packages like Numpy to operate on large numerical data effectively from Python code.  My Numpy tutorial may serve as a decent introduction: https://github.com/embray/notebooks/blob/master/numpy.ipynb  If you're going to use Python for scientific code you have to get familiar with Numpy (which fortunately is mostly intuitive--mostly...).