# Is it possible to speed up an element-by-element array operation in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I have a list of times (called times in my code, produced by the code suggested to me in the thread [astropy.io fits efficient element access of a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315325/astropy-io-fits-efficient-element-access-of-a-large-table)) and I want to do some statistical tests for periodicity, using Zn^2 and epoch folding tests. Some steps in the code take quite a while to run, and I am wondering if there is a faster way to do it. I have tried the equivalent map and lambda functions, but that takes even longer. My list of times has several hundred or maybe thousands of elements, depending on the dataset. Here is my code:

```
phase=[(x-mintime)*testfreq[m]-int((x-mintime)*testfreq[m]) for x in times]
# the above step takes 3 seconds for the dataset I am using for testing
# testfreq[m] is just one of several hundred frequencies I am testing
# times is of type numpy.ndarray

phasebin=[int(ph*numbins)for ph in phase]
# 1 second (numbins is 20)

powerarray=[phasebin.count(n) for n in range(0,numbins-1)]
# 0.3 seconds

poweravg=np.mean(powerarray)
chisq[m]=sum([(pow-poweravg)**2/poweravg for pow in powerarray])
# the above 2 steps are very quick


for n in range(0,maxn):  # maxn is 3
    cosparam=sum([(np.cos(2*np.pi*(n+1)*ph)) for ph in phase])
    sinparam=sum([(np.sin(2*np.pi*(n+1)*ph)) for ph in phase])
    # these steps each take 4 seconds

    z2[m,n]=sum(z2[m,])+(cosparam**2+sinparam**2)/count
    # this is quick (count is the number of times)
```

As this steps through several hundred frequencies on either side of frequencies identified through an FFT search, it takes a very long time to run. The same functionality in a lower level language runs much more quickly, but I need some of the Python modules for plotting, etc. I am hoping that Python can be persuaded to do some of the operations, particularly the phase, phasebin, powerarray, cosparam, and sinparam calculations, significantly faster, but I am not sure how to make this happen. Can anyone tell me how this can be done, or do I have to write and call functions in C or fortran? I know that this could be done in a few minutes e.g. in fortran, but this Python code takes hours as it is.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Seems like ```phase``` could be done in two steps: ```phase = (times-mintime)*testfreq[m]; phase = phase - phase.astype(np.intxx)```.  ```phase``` would then be an ndarray with the same shape as ```times```.

Comment: Each iteration of the for loop assigns a new value to , ```cosparam``` and ```sinparam``` - that cannot be what you intended - they only reflect the last value of ```n```.

Comment: Yes, the z2 parameter is the important one in this case, and it is calculated correctly from cosparam and sinparam and stored in an array so that it can be graphed vs. frequency (for each value of n) at the endof the script. The cosparam and sinparam parameters need to be calculated for each value of n and for each frequency. The code is correct for the calculations. I would simply like to know how to make it run faster. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you wwii for the advice about phase. That code runs about a thousand times faster (literally) now. I was getting an error which caused me to change the code and add the for loops to multiply by a scalar, but it seems that is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of Python lists, you could use the `numpy` library, it is much faster for linear algebra type operations. For example to add two arrays in an element-wise fashion

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
>>> a + b
array([ 3,  5,  7,  9, 11])
```

Similarly, you can multiply arrays by scalars which multiplies each element as you'd expect

```
>>> 2 * a
array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10])
```

As far as speed, here is the Python list equivalent of adding two lists

```
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> d = [2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [i+j for i,j in zip(c,d)]
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Then timing the two

```
>>> from timeit import timeit

>>> setup = '''
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])'''
>>> timeit('a+b', setup)
0.521275608325351

>>> setup = '''
c = [1,2,3,4,5]
d = [2,3,4,5,6]'''
>>> timeit('[i+j for i,j in zip(c,d)]', setup)
1.2781205834379108
```

In this small example `numpy` was more than twice as fast.

Comment: Sorry, I used the word "list" too freely. The "list" of times is actually of type numpy.ndarray. Therefore all of the derivative objects are also of that type. I wonder if there is code that can speed it up even further.

Comment: In that case, if you have working code that you'd like to tune for speed I'd recommend taking a hop over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as this is more their kind of question.

Comment: I think (most of) your code is actually using lists, not numpy arrays, because you're using list comprehensions, which make intermediate lists.  To get the most out of numpy, you need to use array methods and vectorized operations instead of for loops and comprehensions.

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking about. If you have examples of how a specific line of my code could be written more efficiently, please post the improved line of code. Thanks.

Comment: CoryKramer and jpkotta you are right that it was using lists, even though I started out with an array. Now that I forced it to use numpy arrays, I can do everything without the for loops and everything goes much more quickly. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop substitute - operating on complete arrays

First multiply `phase` by 2*pi*n using [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
phase = np.arange(10)
maxn = 3
ens = np.arange(1, maxn+1) # array([1, 2, 3])
two_pi_ens = 2*np.pi*ens
b = phase * two_pi_ens[:, np.newaxis]
```

`b.shape` is (3,10) one *row* for each value of `range(1, maxn)`

Take the cosine then sum to get the three cosine parameters

```
c = np.cos(b)
c_param = c.sum(axis = 1)   # c_param.shape is 3
```

Take the sine then sum to get the three sine parameters

```
s = np.sin(b)
s_param = s.sum(axis = 1)   # s_param.shape is 3
```

Sum of the squares divided by count

```
d = (np.square(c_param) + np.square(s_param)) / count
# d.shape is (3,)
```

Assign to `z2`

```
for n in range(maxn):
    z2[m,n] = z2[m,:].sum() + d[n]
```

That loop is doing a cumulative sum.  numpy ndarrays have a [`cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html#numpy.cumsum) method.
If `maxn` is small (3 in your case) it may not be noticeably faster.

```
z2[m,:] += d
z2[m,:].cumsum(out = z2[m,:])
```

To illustrate:

```
>>> a = np.ones((3,3))
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> m = 1
>>> d = (1,2,3)
>>> a[m,:] += d
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> a[m,:].cumsum(out = a[m,:])
array([ 2.,  5.,  9.])
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just had to change the last bit to make it work like before: `z2[m,n] = sum(z2[m,])+d[n]` instead of adding the sum to d (z2 starts as all zeros and the second value z2[m,1] needs to have z2[m,0] added to it and so on).

Comment: I should add that your code runs a factor of 20 faster. The only downside is now I no longer have time for a break while my script is running.

Comment: @MirandaJackson are ```z2[m,0]```, ```z2[m,1]```, and ```z2[m,2]``` initially all zero?